# Per se number of row in a numpy array - Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, numbers, row

Imagine that I have a numpy array of 'n' rows by 'm' elements, i.e. shape = (n,m).

If the array is called xrandom and I have a routine like the one shown below and additionally I want to know the row number, what alternatives do I have? (I know that if I had done things differently, I would have the row number, however, I want to know if there is another way to know the row number per se:

```py
for xreg in xrandom:
       print(xreg, -line number of xreg-)
```

I haven't tried anything as I don't know how to.

Comment: `xrandom.shape[0]` or `len(xrandom)`

Comment: In your example `xreg` will always be an array and will always exist in `xrandom`.  For the your use case will these statements be true?  If `xreg` could be a scalar np.where could help.  If `xreg` may not exist in `random` any code would have to recognise this possibility.  Further what is required if `xreg` exists more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for row_number, row in enumerate(xrandom):
  print(row, row_number)
```

Comment: It does help to enumerate the records, but not to get the row number within the array directly. Maybe I phrased the question wrong. I meant more like if I have a record from a numpy array, Is there any intrinsic way to know what place it occupies in the array?

Comment: A row (or any other element) does not have an 'intrinsic' row number or place.  `xrandom[10,:]` is the the 10th row, but nothing about it identifies that `10`.  `xrandom[10,11]` is an element of the array, but again, no `10` or `11` identifier.  Pandas maintains row and column indices, but for `numpy` it's strictly by position.